# Extract a CSV from a ZIP file downloaded from the web, then format and import that CSV to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, web-scraping, vba

There is a ZIP data file at `http://portal.flmmis.com/FLPublic/Provider_ManagedCare/Provider_ManagedCare_Registration/tabId/77/Default.aspx?linkid=pml`which contains a CSV that I need to utilize in my Access database.

This file is updated daily which is why the process needs to be automated. After extracting the CSV from the ZIP file into an Excel file, I need to replace all commas within the file with a space.

After that I need to import that file into a database titled `Network_DB` so that I can produce reports based on that and other data sets. It is comma delimited.

I have no idea where to start. I've seen suggestions for Python, PowerShell, Excel macros...the whole nine yards. I'll say that I don't have access to Python at work and I'm unfamiliar with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Access already then `VBA` is the easiest way to tackle this problem.

To download a file from the web you can use this snippet:

```
Sub downloadUrl(url As String, destinationFile As String)
    Dim htp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim stream As New ADODB.Stream

    'Request file
    With htp
        .Open "GET", url, false
        .send
    End With

    'Save to file
    With stream
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .write htp.responseBody
        .SaveToFile destinationFile
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Then call this function like this

```
downloadUrl "http://portal.flmmis.com/FLPublic/Provider_ManagedCare/Provider_ManagedCare_Registration/tabId/77/Default.aspx?linkid=pml", "C:\Users\Public\test.csv"
```

To import a CSV to MS Access you can use one of the import wizards to help you.

Ps.: I tried to access the provided link but it seems to be offline for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *DownLoadFile* function here:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

to download the file. Then unzip it using a function like this:

```
Public Function UnzipFile( _
    ByVal ZipFile As String, _
    Optional ByRef DestinationFolder As String) _
    As Boolean

    Const LocalAppData  As String = "LOCALAPPDATA"
    Const OverWriteAll  As Long = &H10&

    Dim ShellApp        As Object
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Result          As Boolean

    ' Any error will cause a return value of False.
    On Error Resume Next

    FileName = Dir(ZipFile, vbNormal)
    If InStr(StrReverse(ZipFile), StrReverse(FileName)) = 1 Then
        ' ZipFile exists.
        If DestinationFolder = "" Then
            ' Find and use user's LocalAppData folder, and return constructed folder name.
            DestinationFolder = Environ(LocalAppData) & "\" & Left(FileName, InStr(FileName, ".")) & "Files"
        End If
        If Dir(DestinationFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            ' Create new destination folder.
            MkDir DestinationFolder
        End If
        If InStr(StrReverse(DestinationFolder), StrReverse(Dir(DestinationFolder, vbDirectory))) = 1 Then
            ' Destination folder existed or has been created successfully.
            Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            ' Unzip files to destination folder.
            ShellApp.Namespace(CVar(DestinationFolder)).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(CVar(ZipFile)).Items, OverWriteAll
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Result = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    UnzipFile = Result

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will take a look at that later this afternoon, it looks like it would fit my needs.